# Subsequence converging strongly in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\phi \in C(\mathbb{R}; (0, \infty))$ be such that$$\lim_{|x| \to \infty} \phi(x) = 0$$and, for $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, define$$Sf(x) := \int_x^{x+1} f(x)\phi(x)\,dx.$$If $\{f_n : n \in \mathbb{R}\} \subset L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is bounded, then does $\{Sf_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ have a subsequence which converges strongly in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M>0$ be such that $|f_n(x)|\le M$ for all $n$ and all $x\ge0$. Then
$$
|Sf_n(x)|\le M\,\sup_{x\le t\le x+1}|\phi(x)|\le M\,\|\phi\|.
$$
This implies that $\{Sf_n\}$ is uniformly bounded and that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}Sf_n(x)=0$ uniformly in $n$.

If $x<y<x+1$, then
$$
|Sf_n(x)-Sf_n(y)|\le\int_x^y|f(t)\,\phi(t)|\,dt+\int_{x+1}^{y+1}|f(t)\,\phi(t)|\,dt\le2\,M\,\|\phi\|\,|x-y|,
$$
proving that $\{Sf_n\}$ is equicontinuous.

By the Ascoli-Arzelà theorem, there is a subsequence $\{Sf_{n^1_k}\}$ that converges uniformly on $[-1,1]$. This subsequence has a subsequence $\{Sf_{n^2_k}\}$ that converges uniformly on $[-2,2]$. Keep on doing this, and consider the diagonal sequence $\{Sf_{n^k_k}\}$. It converges uniformly on any interval $[-k,k]$. Now use that it converges to $0$ uniformly in $n$ as $|x|\to\infty$ to conclude that in fact it converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$.